# How to make file upload with form values in Spring?

Tags: spring, file-upload

Why do I get "bad request" when I try to make a file upload with Spring?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView index(//final @ModelAttribute AddCommand addCommand,
                          @RequestParam("name") String name,
                          @RequestParam("desc") String desc,
                          //@ModelAttribute("uploadedFile") UploadedFile uploadedFile,
                          @RequestParam("file") UploadedFile uploadedFile,
                          BindingResult result,
                          HttpServletRequest request) {
```

I'm not sure how to achieve what I'm trying to do since the docs all completely different how to make a simple file upload with name and description:

```
<% /** http://localhost:8083/admin/add **/ %>

<%@ page import="web.command.AddCommand" %>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/taglibs.jsp" %>

<h3>Add New</h3>

<form:form commandName="<%=AddCommand.NAME%>" enctype="multipart/form-data"
            method="post"
           role="form">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="desc">Description</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="desc" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>File: </td>
            <td><input type="file" name="file" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form:form>
```

What is the way it should be? I can make the form submit without the file but when I tried adding file upload to my form it was undoable to do this simple thing because Spring, XML and Java are way too verbose and have way too many settings and configurations. There should be one obvious way to do it and there isn't an obvious clear way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do it the way it is described in the Spring tutorial on how to do file uploads?

http://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Comment: No I can't. Not in a clear way. I get "Bad Request" trying to do it since Spring makes it difficult to achieve something simple. I don't even get a stacktrace, only "Bad Request" because Spring has made it difficult to do something simple.

Comment: According to your code, you haven't followed the instructions provided in the tutorial. For example you are passing an "UploadedFile" rather than a "MultipartFile". If you can't be bothered to follow a simple tutorial, I won't be helping any further.

Comment: I do want it to work, but the name "UploadedFile" was from another Spring tutorial which had only a file and not also a text field. Now I think it seems like I must add some XML to enable the MultiPartFile but it doesn't say which XML. I've worked with other frameworks where it was easy and obvious to do this and with Spring not even the error message is comprehensible. Now I'm trying this: `public ModelAndView index(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request                          ) {´ and I don't think that it will work.

Comment: Much better to follow the tutorial provided by Spring when there is one. If you read it you will see that you just need to create a configuration class which defines a MultipartConfigElement bean. No XML involved.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it seems to have started working when I added the XML for the file upload type.

Comment: Is that the MultipartConfigElement or something else?

Comment: Yes, I had to add this which was not clear where or what to add, I had to guess that this was going to work: `<bean id="multipartResolver"   class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">...`